# Github cli in Action not running workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

Trying to setup a scheduled workflow that triggers a workflow with particular settings on different branches (which for us equates to different projects)

```
- run: |
      gh workflow run 'full_branch_manual.yml' -F RunTests=true -F ValidateOnly=true  -r ${{matrix.TARGET_BRANCH}}
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

But whilst the trigger runs, it fails to trigger the target workflow, it does not mark the triggering workflow with any error.  I do notice that it does not output anything in the logs as a result of running the command though.

I have checked the doco (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows) it says it can run any "GitHub CLI command"

Note I looked at Reuseable workflows but I cannot see how to specify run the workflow for a particular branch.

Anyone managed to achieve this?

Comment: Commits created by the default GITHUB_TOKEN do not trigger workflows, because that could lead to loops. Similarly, I could imaging that you can't use it to trigger a workflow. If the former explains the latter, then one option would be to create a personal access token and use that to authenticate.

Comment: FYI - I can confirm that generating a Personal Access Token and using that as part of the GITHUB_TOKEN
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN_PAT }}

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that using a Personal Access Token did work

```
 env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN_PAT }}
```